# Open a JOptionPane with a button from other class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

I would like to know of how do I make a link in a button of the main class inside of a `JPanel` that close the `JFrame` and opens a `JOptionPane` from another class, any help will be welcome

This is my main class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class StartingScreen extends JFrame{
    JFrame StartingScreen = new JFrame();
    JPanel SidePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel CenterPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel BottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton ButtonNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
    JButton ButtonLoadGame = new JButton("Load Game");
    JButton ButtonDeleteGame = new JButton("Delete Game");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StartingScreen();
        FileLoader FL = new FileLoader();
    }

    StartingScreen(){
        //Configuration of the JPanel
        super("StartingScreen");
        StartingScreen.setSize(880,520);
        StartingScreen.setResizable(false);
        StartingScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Configuration of the panels
        SidePanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        SidePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,520));
        BottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(880,80));
        BottomPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        CenterPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        //Configuration of the buttons
        ButtonNewGame.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        ButtonNewGame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280,130));
        ButtonNewGame.setActionCommand("Add Credits");
        ButtonNewGame.addActionListener(this);
        ButtonLoadGame.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        ButtonLoadGame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280,130));
        ButtonDeleteGame.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        ButtonDeleteGame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280,130));

        //Adding components
        StartingScreen.add(SidePanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        StartingScreen.add(CenterPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        StartingScreen.add(BottomPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        SidePanel.add(ButtonNewGame);
        SidePanel.add(ButtonLoadGame);
        SidePanel.add(ButtonDeleteGame);

        //Making it visible(Important to be at the end)
        StartingScreen.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is my secondary class where I store the option pane I want to open:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewGame {
    String[] classes ={
        "Paladin",
        "Mage",
        "Warlock",
    };
    int classes_index=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose a class", "Classes", 0,
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, classes, 0);
}
```

The button I want to link is `ButtomNewGme` in the panel `SidePanel`.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) ..

Comment: .. 4) `public class StartingScreen extends JFrame{ JFrame StartingScreen = new JFrame(); ..`  That code both extends frame & keeps a reference to a standard frame. Do the latter, not the former. 5) `StartingScreen.add(..,BorderLayout.WEST); .. StartingScreen.add(..,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);` This uses a combination of compass & logical constraints. It's better to consistently use the logical constraints (which adapt to the default direction of the text of a language, for e.g.) consistently, so `StartingScreen.add(..,BorderLayout.LINE_START); .. StartingScreen.add(..,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I set the size of the jpanel without preferredsize?, setsize doesn't work if I have multiple jpanels in one jframe

Comment: *"how do I set the size of the jpanel without preferredsize?"* Are they custom painted panels, or do they contain components? Did you read the top two voted answers in the linked Q&A? I think they answered at least part of your question. What don't you understand after reading those answers? BTW - where is the MCVE / SSCCE? Voting to close for lack of one.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do your showOptionDialog in constructor (or some other method for best practice) of class NewGame. And to open this JOptionPane, you have to :

```
ButtonNewGame.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
     new NewGame();
});
```

Comment: forgot to say, this minimal code will works only with Java 8 +

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code will compile because you have `ButtonNewGame.addActionListener(this);` but your class doesn't implement `ActionListener`.

To fix that, one of the things you'll need to do is write an `actionPerformed(...)` method. That will be called when the button is pressed, and I think that's where you want to make an instance of `NewGame` and at that point your chooser dialog will appear.